# ionic 4 - is there any way to implement google ads in between ion list after 3 items?

Tags: android, typescript, admob, ionic4, ads

i want to implement google banner ad after 3 items in ion list i have tried a different methods, but my problem isn't solved.can anyone help me out to solve the problem?

Here's what I'd like to attempt:

`

```html
<div *ngFor="let n of news;let i=index;">
    <ion-card class="myCard" *ngIf="news.typ === 'N'">
      <h3>
        <b>{{n.title}}</b>
      </h3>
    </ion-card>
    <div *ngIf="(i+1)%3 ===0">
      <!-- INSERT AD AFTER THE3rd ITEM -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

your using {{news.title}} but news is a complete array, you have to use n.title

```
<div *ngFor="let n of news;let i=index;">
<ion-card class="myCard" *ngIf="n.typ === 'N'">
  <h3>
    <b>{{n.title}}</b>
  </h3>
</ion-card>
<div *ngIf="(i+1)%3 ===0">
  <!-- INSERT AD AFTER THE3rd ITEM -->
  <b>Advertisement</b>
</div>
```

Happy coding :-)